# How are Views injected into the UI using PRISM and MEF?

Tags: mvvm, prism, mef

I have already searched some tutorials and even looked pluralsite Introduction to PRISM. However, most examples based on using unity containers and the some lack of information on how to implement this feature with Mef container.
My simple helloworld module is based on [web tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229931/Understand-MVVM-Using-PRISM-by-Hello-World-Silverl#). My code is the same except I’m stuck only on HelloModule and using Mef, not Unity as tutorial shows:

The main my problem how to initialize my view with my view model. The only working way I have found via experimenting is to initialize view-model in View constructor:

```
HelloView.xaml.cs
namespace Hello.View
{
    [Export]
    public partial class HelloView : UserControl, IHelloView
    {
        public HelloView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Model = new HelloViewModel(this);
        }

        public IHelloViewModel Model
        {
            //get { return DataContext as IHelloViewModel; }
            get { return (IHelloViewModel)DataContext; }
            set { DataContext = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And standard module initialization code:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(HelloModule), InitializationMode=InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]
    public class HelloModule : IModule
    {
        IRegionManager _regionManager;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public HelloModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ContentRegion].Add(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<HelloView>());
        }
    }
```

However, can someone tell the correct way how to this things, I this it must be done in Module initialization section.

Comment: initialize view-model in View constructor is a good way. what problem do you have doing it like that?

Comment: With Unity, they initialize view-model via containers. It makes me searching equivalent way in mef? But if you say it good way I will not stickle much, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

MatthiasG shows the way to define modules in MEF. Note that the view itself does not implement IModule. However, the interesting part of using MEF with PRISM is how to import the modules into your UI at startup.

I can only explain the system in principle here, but it might point you in the right direction. There are always numerous approaches to everything, but this is what I understood to be best practice and what I have made very good experiences with:

**Bootstrapping**

As with Prism and Unity, it all starts with the Bootstrapper, which is derived from `MefBootstrapper` in `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions`. The bootstrapper sets up the MEF container and thus imports all types, including services, views, ViewModels and models.

**Exporting Views (modules)**

This is the part MatthiasG is referring to. My practice is the following structure for the GUI modules:

- The model exports itself as its concrete type (can be an interface too, see MatthiasG), using `[Export(typeof(MyModel)]` attribute. Mark with `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]` to indicate, that only one instance is created (singleton behavior).
- The ViewModel exports itself as its concrete type just like the model and imports the Model via constructor injection:

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public class MyViewModel(MyModel model) 
  { 
      _model = model; 
  }
- The View imports the ViewModel via constructor injection, the same way the ViewModel imports the Model
- And now, this is important: The View exports itself with a specific attribute, which is derived from the 'standard' `[Export]` attribute. Here is an example:

```cs
[ViewExport(RegionName = RegionNames.DataStorageRegion)]
public partial class DataStorageView
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public DataStorageView(DataStorageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

**The [ViewExport] attribute**

The `[ViewExport]` attribute does two things: Because it derives from `[Export]` attribute, it tells the MEF container to import the View. As what? This is hidden in it's defintion: The constructor signature looks like this:

```cs
public ViewExportAttribute() : base(typeof(UserControl)) {}
```

By calling the constructor of `[Export]` with type of `UserControl`, every view gets registered as `UserControl` in the MEF container.

Secondly, it defines a property `RegionName` which will later be used to decide in which Region of your Shell UI the view should be plugged. The RegionName property is the only member of the interface `IViewRegionRegistration`. The attribute class:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Marks a UserControl for exporting it to a region with a specified name
/// </summary>
[Export(typeof(IViewRegionRegistration))]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
[MetadataAttribute]
public sealed class ViewExportAttribute : ExportAttribute, IViewRegionRegistration
{
    public ViewExportAttribute() : base(typeof(UserControl)) {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the region to export the View to
    /// </summary>
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
}
```

**Importing the Views**

Now, the last crucial part of the system is a *behavior*, which you attach to the regions of your shell: `AutoPopulateExportedViews` behavior. This imports all of your module from the MEF container with this line:

```cs
[ImportMany] 
private Lazy<UserControl, IViewRegionRegistration>[] _registeredViews;
```

This imports all types registered as `UserControl` from the container, if they have a metadata attribute, which implements `IViewRegionRegistration`. Because your `[ViewExport]` attribute does, this means that you import every type marked with `[ViewExport(...)]`.

The last step is to plug the Views into the regions, which the bahvior does in it's `OnAttach()` property:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// A behavior to add Views to specified regions, if the View has been exported (MEF) and provides metadata
/// of the type IViewRegionRegistration.
/// </summary>
[Export(typeof(AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior : RegionBehavior, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    protected override void OnAttach()
    {
        AddRegisteredViews();
    }

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        AddRegisteredViews();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add View to region if requirements are met
    /// </summary>
    private void AddRegisteredViews()
    {
        if (Region == null) return;

        foreach (var view in _registeredViews
            .Where(v => v.Metadata.RegionName == Region.Name)
            .Select(v => v.Value)
            .Where(v => !Region.Views.Contains(v)))
            Region.Add(view);

    }

    [ImportMany()] 
    private Lazy<UserControl, IViewRegionRegistration>[] _registeredViews;
}
```

Notice `.Where(v => v.Metadata.RegionName == Region.Name)`. This uses the RegionName property of the attribute to get only those Views that are exported for the specific region, you are attaching the behavior to.

The behavior gets attached to the regions of your shell in the bootstrapper:

```cs
protected override IRegionBehaviorFactory ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()
{
    ViewModelInjectionBehavior.RegionsToAttachTo.Add(RegionNames.ElementViewRegion);

    var behaviorFactory = base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors();
    behaviorFactory.AddIfMissing("AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior", typeof(AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior));
}
```

We've come full circle, I hope, this gets you an idea of how the things fall into place with MEF and PRISM.

And, if you're still not bored: This is perfect:

[Mike Taulty's screencast](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/31/silverlight-4-screencasts-the-managed-extensibility-framework-mef.aspx)

Comment: Hi Marc, great write up. I'm just trying to get started with MEF and PRISM and to be honest I'm getting completely lost. I can't find any good basic tutorials that walk you through all of this, the MSDN one only covers bits and pieces and the example projects are far too complicated for me to follow without knowing what I'm looking at. Do you know any good tutorials on MEF and PRISM you could point me to?

Comment: @user1122909 Great to her you like it. Have you had a look at Mike Taulty's Screencast (link in my post)? Take a couple of hours and you'll really learn a lot. I basically learned PRISM/MEF with these videos and nothing else. The PRISM manual can be a lookup, too, but I wouldn't have too high expectations here...

Comment: No will go have a look now, thanks very much. Just in the mean time, I don't suppose you have any thoughts on a question I posted re: MEF/Prism? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526287/wpf-mef-prism-initial-region-loading

Comment: Oh thanks for this descriptive answer. Now this makes sense to me!

Answer (score 1):

The way you implemented `HelloView` means that the `View` has to know the exact implementation of `IHelloViewModel` which is in some scenarios fine, but means that you wouldn't need this `interface`.

For the examples I provide I'm using `property injection`, but `constructor injection` would also be fine.

If you want to use the `interface` you can implement it like this:

```cs
[Export(typeof(IHelloView)]
public partial class HelloView : UserControl, IHelloView
{
    public HelloView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import]
    public IHelloViewModel Model
    {
        get { return DataContext as IHelloViewModel; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IHelloViewModel))]
public class HelloViewModel : IHelloViewModel
{
}
```

Otherwise it would look like this:

```cs
[Export(typeof(IHelloView)]
public partial class HelloView : UserControl, IHelloView
{
    public HelloView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import]
    public HelloViewModel Model
    {
        get { return DataContext as HelloViewModel; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
}

[Export]
public class HelloViewModel
{
}
```

One more thing: If you don't want to change your `Views` or provide several implementations of them, you don't need an `interface` for them.