# how to add many regions into mef container

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, containers

i am trying to register multiple regions to my region like in Unity:

```
public class ModuleA : IModule
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public ModuleA(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ToolbarRegion];

        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
    }
}
```

}

but i can't succeed to do it with MEF

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(ModuleAModule))]
public class ModuleAModule : IModule
{
    [Import]
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;


    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(ContentView));

        IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ToolbarRegion];

    }
}
```

i can get the region, but i don't know how to translate the resolving into MEF.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here. Maybe it helps..

[SO Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289178/wpf-prism-mef-mvvm-injecting-view-with-view-model-what-is-correct-way

Comment: Hi Marc, this is not the case...
my problem with MEF is how i do the following:
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());
        region.Add(_container.Resolve<ToolbarView>());

Comment: @kaycee In your first sample each region is unique?

Comment: yes... i try to do it with region.Add(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<new ToolbarView>());
but i think since MEF is a singleton it's not possible