# Regions in Prism Modules

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef, modularity

Looking a way to register regions in the modules.
I'm using latest PRISM with MEF.

Also using ViewExport to autopopulate Views
(shown here :: [How are Views injected into the UI using PRISM and MEF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289178/how-are-views-injected-into-the-ui-using-prism-and-mef?answertab=active#answer-15290547))

When Adding the "AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior" error pops up:

> The Region property cannot be set after Attach method has been called.

**MyMefBootstrapper.cs**

```
protected override IRegionBehaviorFactory ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()
{
    var factory = base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors();
    factory.AddIfMissing("AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior", typeof(AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior));

    return factory;
}
```

**Shell.xaml**

```
<Window ...>
    <ContentControl Name="MainRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainRegion}" />
</Window>
```

**ModuleX.xaml**

```
<UserControl ...>
        <Viewbox>
            <Grid ...>

                <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="HomeScreen_LeftSide" />
                <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="HomeScreen_RightSide" />

            </Grid>
        </Viewbox> 
</UserControl>
```

The Point of the solution is to add a contentcontrol to shell which manages the masterpages (coming from module). The module itself can contain other modules / views.

Any good solution for this kind of architecture?